# Python Croniter get time in 24 hour format

Tags: python, datetime, croniter

I have tried the Python croniter's get_prev() method to get the last scheduled time based on a cron string and current time.

When I tried it in windows machine it returned the value in 24 hour format.
But when I tried the same code via AWS glue (possibly Linux) , it returned scheduled time in 12 hour format without AM/PM notation.

Is there any way to force the croniter to return time in 24 hour format always.

```
        currentTime=datetime.now()
        print(currentTime)
        cron = croniter(cron_str, currentTime)
        lastCronScheduleTime=cron.get_prev(datetime)
        print(lastCronScheduleTime)
```

Comment: Probably depends on your locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `get_prev` returns a `datetime.datetime` instance.

When a `datetime` is passed to `print()`, it is first converted to string by calling its `__str__` method. The `__str__` method calls `isoformat()` ([see python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__)).

In other words, the output from your example should be in  ISO 8601 format, which always uses 24-hour notation.

My guess is you are seeing different hour values because your Windows and Linux machines use different timezones, and `datetime.now()` returns a naive datetime in system's default timezone.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct the AWS glue instance running in Sydney region was still using UTC as local time zone.